# ASP Calendar with February 29 and 30

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, calendar

I have a requirement where I have to allow the user to enter February 29 and February 30 as valid date. This is for accounting purposes, and it is not the norm, it only required for specific forms.

Right now it is a numeric open field and the user manually enters the date and we don't perform any date validations because they will fail.

Is there any way I can include those 2 days into the ASP Calendar control so the user simply select it as they normally do for other dates? (We are using C# with webforms in Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: better to use `DD` `MM` `YY` combobxes

Comment: can you show us currently how you are initializing and or setting the Calendar's Selected date when you load your form..? you could do something like the following for the calendar control when you first load the page.. 
`Calendar_1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);` and you could also figure out if you can set the enabled property for that particular day(s) as well

Comment: Updated the question to correct how the user interacts with the form. It is not a datetime field, it is a regular textbox with a javascript validation to make sure the user enters the correct numbers for a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a Regular Expression Validator,

this checks whether the entry is in the correct format before post.

it would look something like this

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_date_entry"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_date_entry" runat="server" 
      ControlToValidate="txt_date_entry" ErrorMessage="Must be Valid Date" 
      ValidationExpression="**Expression**"  Display="Dynamic">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Replace Expression with the format you wish to compare it against.

Below will check any dateformat is correct (even leap year dates) as long as it is in either the dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy etc.

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Google Validation Expressions for the format you wish

Comment: That is I would suggest using this if you MUST require a text box entry and not a calendar extension or combo boxes.

Comment: This is the requirement: Must be equal to or less than current date and entered in YYYYMMDD date format. Valid date includes Feb 29 or Feb 30. - They are hoping for the calendar but they also understand and accept a textbox where they enter the data.

Comment: With these requirements you should really use javascript datetime.parse method, RegEx is ok for making sure you cant type anything you shouldn't but it doesn't understand restrictions such as before today etc.see next answer for example, as for the calendar control im sure if you search SO someone will have done it but I have never done it myself

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Parse Method Example

```
   function dateValidation() 
{
   var obj = document.getElementById("<%=txtDate.ClientID%>"); 
   var day = obj.value.split("/")[0];
   var month = obj.value.split("/")[1]; 
   var year = obj.value.split("/")[2];
   if ((day<1 || day >31) || (month<1&&month>12)&&(year.length != 4)) 
   {
      alert("Invalid Format");return false; 
   }

   else

   {
      var dt = new Date(year, month-1, day); 
      var today = new Date();
      if((dt.getDate() != day) || (dt.getMonth() != month-1) ||(dt.getFullYear()!=year) || (dt>today)) 
      {
         alert("Invalid Date");return false; 
      }
   }

}
```